# dry run command not working as required

Tags: svn, merge

I am trying to test conflicts using --dry-run option and following is my command:

```
svn merge -c4461,4462 --dry-run https://<Confidential-URL>/svn/repos/transitionportal/branches/BR_3591_MULTILINGUAL
```

The output of this command shows that there are conflicts. Following is the output:

```
--- Merging r4461 into '.':
U    test\testfile.txt
--- Merging r4462 into '.':
C    test\testfile.txt
Summary of conflicts:
  Text conflicts: 1
```

However, when I do the merge directly i.e.without the --dry-run option or use Tortoise SVN GUI for merging, it directly merges without giving any conflict.

```
--- Merging r4461 into '.':
U    test\testfile.txt
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r4461 into '.':
 U   .
--- Merging r4462 into '.':
G    test\testfile.txt
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r4462 into '.':
 G   .
```

Any reason why dry run is giving conflicts? 
Someone please help me.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is interesting. I can't really say without looking at the history and the files involved, but I'm willing to assume that somehow revision 4461 made a change in `testfile.txt` that prevented it from being conflicting in revision 4462.

Let's say you branched off revision 4000, you made one change on your branch for revision 4450, and now you're merging the changes 4461 and 4462 from your trunk to this branch.

It could be that the merge of 4461 somehow fixed the conflict that Subversion detected between revision 4450 and revision 4462. After all, a dry run doesn't actually modify the files touched. I can't think of a circumstance right off hand where this would happen. Is it possible that you had merged your current working directory to the branch previously, and that revision 4461 would include that?)

When you use the `-c` parameter, one change at a time are merged in. These two are equivalent:

```
$ svn merge -r45:46 ...
```

However, these are not quite equivalent:

```
$ svn merge -c45,46  ...
$ svn merge -r44:46  ...
```

The first will merge twice (as you see. It merges version 45 and then version 46). The second one creates a change set and merges that change set, so only a single merge is done. As far as I know, the final results are the same, but the operation is different.

It would have been interesting to see if you had done this:

```
$ svn merge -c4460:4462 ....
```

and see if you got the same merge conflict.

Sorry about the broad answer. It's always difficult to say what Subversion is thinking without looking at the merge history, the common ancestor, and the previous changes. A merge conflict happens when the work in one branch (say changing a line) also takes place in the second branch. I can't see right off hand how the initial merge will solve this, but apparently it did.

Comment: Hi David,thku for your response. It is helping me to find the cause. Yes you are correct files involved in revision 4462 are the same as that in rev 4461. Changes in 4462 depends on rev 4461 and as you said -c option means 2 merges, while merging 4462 it does not conside 4461's changes and hence gives a conflict. `-c` option does not take `:`. So I am left with -r option. But in `-r` option there is a limitation that i cannot use multiple revision numbers. In my case there are chances that I can have more that 2 revision numbers. `-r 4432,4462,4465` doesn't work. Can you suggest some solution?

Comment: You can specify `-r` multiple times for each range of revisions you're merging. `-r` takes a range you want to merge while `-c` takes a comma separated list of individual revisions. However, using `-r` multiple times also ends up doing multiple merges. I usually don't worry too much about conflicts when I do cherry pick merging because you have to merge, you have to merge, and if there are conflicts, you handle them. What else are you going to do?

Comment: What i want to do is, i have a script which checks for merge conflicts using `svn merge --dry-run` option. If there are conflicts the script will send mail and exit the script. There are possibilities that it will have multiple revisions not necessarily in range. So not able to figure out how to do this. Can you suggest some thing?

Comment: Just because no *conflicts* were found doesn't mean everything is copacetic. Merges can fail because the two parts of the merged file conflict with each other. Imagine someone on the branch setting `frobercate = true` in the top of the file, but some on trunk had set it to `false` in the middle of the file. This would be a conflict, but it wouldn't show up as one because the file was modified in two separate places. I hope you're not trying to completely automate merges.

Comment: (continued). Otherwise, you could probably live with a few false conflict warnings. The only way I see around this is to break the merge down into separate sets. You do the first set, dry run, then merge. then do the second set, dry run, then merge.

Comment: Yeah David, this is what I did. Separated the merges taking one revision at a time. Did dry-run and then merged it if no conflicts. And it is working perfectly. Thanks for the help.